# Incorrect JSON, character encoding or unrecognized file format

Tags: php, json, magento, serialization, character-encoding

I am using Magento, and this particular value should be a valid json that I can parse. It appears that something has gone wrong with the character encoding. I am getting this.

```
a:10:{s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:5:"title";s:25:"the-goose-will-attack.jpg";s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:10:"order_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/order/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:8:"fullpath";s:102:"/var/www/mageprodcory/mage-webroot/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:4:"size";s:5:"42421";s:5:"width";i:450;s:6:"height";i:600;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"94b0992d58b4478d13a2";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:3:"133";s:3:"key";s:20:"94b0992d58b4478d13a2";}}}
```

It almost looks like valid json, but the `;s:25:` type of stuff doesn't belong. It should be json, but I suppose it's also possible to be some other file format.

I couldn't find any character encoding info on the `;s:25:` type characters, mostly because it's difficult to search for. I've tried disabling magic quotes, but that's not the cause.

Any idea why the JSON is incorrect, or what file format this text may be, and how I can parse it in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This string is not json. It's serialized value. Run this code:

```
<?php

var_dump(unserialize('a:10:{s:4:"type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:5:"title";s:25:"the-goose-will-attack.jpg";s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:10:"order_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/order/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:8:"fullpath";s:102:"/var/www/mageprodcory/mage-webroot/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg";s:4:"size";s:5:"42421";s:5:"width";i:450;s:6:"height";i:600;s:10:"secret_key";s:20:"94b0992d58b4478d13a2";s:3:"url";a:2:{s:5:"route";s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption";s:6:"params";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:3:"133";s:3:"key";s:20:"94b0992d58b4478d13a2";}}}'));
```

Output would be like this:

```
array(10) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["title"]=>
  string(25) "the-goose-will-attack.jpg"
  ["quote_path"]=>
  string(68) "/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg"
  ["order_path"]=>
  string(68) "/media/custom_options/order/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg"
  ["fullpath"]=>
  string(102) "/var/www/mageprodcory/mage-webroot/media/custom_options/quote/t/h/94b0992d58b4478d13a2376f645d3b7c.jpg"
  ["size"]=>
  string(5) "42421"
  ["width"]=>
  int(450)
  ["height"]=>
  int(600)
  ["secret_key"]=>
  string(20) "94b0992d58b4478d13a2"
  ["url"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["route"]=>
    string(35) "sales/download/downloadCustomOption"
    ["params"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "133"
      ["key"]=>
      string(20) "94b0992d58b4478d13a2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I've cross posted this answer to my question on magento.stackexchange. http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/105127/32819 Let me know if this is a problem.